# Animation inside listview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-animation

I have a custom listview inside fragment where data is coming from server in which there a field of date of birth.If current date matches to date of birth i need to show an animation or birthday cake.I have no idea how to do this.
Any one please help me to do this.

Comment: you can use svg for that

Comment: can you elaborate..what is svg and functionality?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: SVG defines the graphics in XML format. you can found lots of example how to use that. may be this url help you https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2302

Comment: @zafarimam can you paste example screenshot what exact animation you want so i can help you

Comment: @Sandy i just need to show a birthday cake with birthday wish in the respected row of listview.

Comment: @zafarimam so you just want to show the cack and wishing message no animation right ?

Comment: @Sandy ..Yes it is also fine if animation is more complex.

Comment: check my answer @zafarimam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So First you need to add you cack and message on the list item view xml file and make its visibility gone

Now on list adapter getview method where you are setting your data just compare the current date with the date that you are getting from the server list for the every list item position

If both date are matched then you just need to set the visibility of cack and you wish message to visible

it will show you cack and message to that position

Try this first let me know if its working then i will also help you for to do animation on that

Comment: I tried it half but now it is completed and working fine. It showing cake and wish with respected row. Thanx a lot.

Comment: I did not get who and why have voted down.? What is the problem with question? I tried to make everything clear. kindly remove down vote with it.

Comment: if you find my answer was correct and it helped you then accept my answer so other to get help from here